# Facebook PHP SDK - Login helper returns error

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

i have created a app witch are using facebook as a login opportunity. My APP worked public fine 1 day ago, but today it started getting this error when my users are logging in:

> Graph returned an error: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

// Setting a local setting
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '****',
  'app_secret' => '****',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

// Setting up the Facebook Helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

//Genneration FaceBook Callback Script
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://gymbilletter.dk/facebook/facebook_callback.php',array('scope' => 'email'));
header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
```

And i have whitelisted my return domain:
[Facebook OAuth Rederictlinks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz5Xb.png)

I have tried to search the interned for answers, but the only answers i get is to update from 5.6.1 to 5.6.2 but i am already using 5.6.3

Comment: I'm having EXACTLY the same problem with several Facebook Apps. All worked fine up to and including yesterday. I suspect there is an issue with Facebook internally?

Comment: see also: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/440347883122288/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Login : Error validating verification code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52095150/facebook-login-error-validating-verification-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i faced same issue over here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52096688/1234825

and tried a different approach

> Facebook seems to have "short of" break its own code. By enabling
>   enfore https, the Validate OAuth url no longer validates.
>
> I have added the following param on my redirect url to bypass the
>   issue
>
> ```
> https://mysubdomain.mysite.gr/index.php?r=site/callbackfb&enforce_https=1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on Graph api version v2.2

If you open Enforce HTTPS on in Facebook Login settings.

Go to you facebook-php-sdk and inside that

```
Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php
```

change $redirectUrl:

```
$redirectUrl = FacebookUrlManipulator::removeParamsFromUrl($redirectUrl, ['state','code']);
```

To

```
$redirectUrl = FacebookUrlManipulator::removeParamsFromUrl($redirectUrl, ['state','code','enforce_https']);
```

Comment: I did actually go in to the facebook app setting and updated the enforce HTTPS to off. I know that all streams to facebook from my site would be over SSL. And after that it worked perfectly.