# Facebook Login : Error validating verification code

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

As of today an application that i have keeps getting the following error while using Facebook Login Api.

> Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog
>   request

Last successfull attempt was yesterday night 2018-08-29 23:40:00 and since then all loging attempts end up to redirect_url mismatch.

My call back url is like

> https://mysubdomain.mysite.gr/index.php?r=site/callbackfb

also tried alternative

> https://mysubdomain.mysite.gr/index.php/site/callbackfb

but still no success.
No change was made to the application and nothing seems to justify the exception. Tried also with latest sdk librady, but i still get the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Might be due to the same bug as mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086528/facebook-php-sdk-login-helper-returns-error

Comment: I posted a similar question but the reason for the error is unknown until now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74918616/facebook-login-through-instagram-error-validating-verification-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook seems to have "short of" break its own code. By enabling enfore https, the Validate OAuth url no longer validates.

I have added the following param on my redirect url to bypass the issue

> https://mysubdomain.mysite.gr/index.php?r=site/callbackfb&enforce_https=1

Answer (score 4):

i am facing same issue today here is solution please check below link :.

[Facebook PHP SDK - Login helper returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086528/facebook-php-sdk-login-helper-returns-error/52090106#52090106)

I'm currently working on Graph api version v2.2

If you open Enforce HTTPS on in Facebook Login settings.

Go to you facebook-php-sdk and inside that

```
Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php
```

change $redirectUrl:

```
$redirectUrl = FacebookUrlManipulator::removeParamsFromUrl($redirectUrl, ['state','code']);
```

To

```
$redirectUrl = FacebookUrlManipulator::removeParamsFromUrl($redirectUrl, ['state','code','enforce_https']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Log into developers.facebook.com and make sure you're using the redirect_uri set on your app.

Failing that, as absurd as this sounds, verify you're using the correct app_secret.

Facebook will give you this instead of just saying "invalid secret" in the response

Comment: Thanks man wasted 2 days for this. Never knew fb will give this intsead of invalid secret

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug from Facebook that started today.

Go to Facebook Developers.
Choose your app.
Go to Facebook Login > Settings
Then uncheck ENFORCE HTTPS

It worked for me :)